# How to serialize an akka "actorRef" that is part of a case class using JsonFormat custom serializer from spray-json?

Tags: scala, serialization, akka, implicit-conversion, spray-json

I need to create a spray-json implicit conversion for a case class that looks like:

```
case class ExampleCaseClass(identified: String, actor: ActorRef)
```

I have been using spray-json to do all of my serialization but I haven't seen anywhere online that explains how to create the JsonFormat implicit conversion for the ActorRef type.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this, or even just point me in the direction of where I could possibly find the answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? `ActorRef` is only meaningful within a single `ActorSystem` instance, so persisting it or sending it to other programs is not going to be useful.

Comment: You are not going to be able to serialize the ActorRef type. Instead I would serialize the actor path, you can get an actor reference from that.

Comment: Firstly, thanks to both of you for getting back to me so quickly!@Tim I have multiple systems all within an akka cluster that share an ActorSystem, so I was going to use this actor reference for when I was required to pass along a reference to an actor that was within this same ActorSystem so that I could send a message to it.

@EmiCareOfCell44, are you saying that it isn't possible to serialize the ActorRef type at all and all I can do is to have a case class with two Strings, and the one that was previously an ActorRef will now just be a String containing the actorRef's path?

Comment: Akka provides a JSON serializer as part of the akka-serialization-jackson module. If you want to use spray-json instead, that would probably work as well, you can take https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0e4d41ad33dbeb00b598cb75b4d29899371bdc8c/akka-serialization-jackson/src/main/scala/akka/serialization/jackson/ActorRefModule.scala as an example of how to do serialization and deserialization. (It might use some internals)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization-classic.html) this works out of the box with Jackson but you need to write a custom serializer for spray.